# Altering template template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I would like to design a class that creates internal types that are variants of types passed as template parameters. Something like the following, non-functional example:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseClass
{
public:
    typedef T InternalType;
    std::vector<InternalType> storage;
};

template <typename Base>
class Injector
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<typename Base::InternalType, typename Base::InternalType> RefinedType;
    Base<RefinedType> refinedStorage;
};

typedef Injector<BaseClass<int> > InjectedInt; // Should store vector<pair<int, int> >
```

Since `Base` is a fully-specified type, `Base<RefinedType> refinedStorage;` will fail to compile. Simply using a template template parameter won't work, as the refined type needs to be based on the nested template's parameter as well as its base type.

How can I implement this pattern of creating types based on both the fully-specified and base types of a template parameter?

EDIT: I would like this to be an arbitrary-depth composite, with multiple injector types performing a cascade of transformations. Thus, passing both the template template parameter and the base parameter becomes pretty unwieldy (particularly when it comes to dealing with the base case of the composite), and an ideal solution would use the more direct syntax.

Comment: Why won't you make it a template template parameter _and_ T parameter, to be used as `Injector<BaseClass, int>`?

Comment: @Petr I thought about that, but ideally I'd like to set this up as an arbitrary-depth composite with changes propagating through multiple layers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by explicitly 're-declaring' the general template inside itself:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseClass
{
public:
    typedef T InternalType;
    std::vector<InternalType> storage;

    template<class T2>
    using Recur = BaseClass<T2>;
};

template <typename Base>
class Injector
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<typename Base::InternalType, typename Base::InternalType> RefinedType;
    typename Base::template Recur<RefinedType> refinedStorage;
};

typedef Injector<BaseClass<int> > InjectedInt; // Should store vector<pair<int, int> >
```

Comment: FWIW, this is how [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)  does it (except they name it `rebind`, and its internal typedef is called `other`).

Answer (score 8):

You could introduce a `rebind` template:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
struct rebind_1st;

template <template <typename... > class Cls, typename A0, typename... Args, typename To>
struct rebind_1st<Cls<A0, Args...>, To> {
    using type = Cls<To, Args...>;
};

template <typename From, typename To>
using rebind_1st_t = typename rebind_1st<From, To>::type;
```

With which your `Injector` becomes:

```
template <typename Base>
class Injector
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<typename Base::InternalType, 
                      typename Base::InternalType> RefinedType;
    rebind_1st_t<Base, RefinedType> refinedStorage;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for a rebinding template, that over-complicates the situation. Simply have a template template type:

```
template<typename>
struct Injector;

template<typename T, template<typename> class Base>
struct Injector<Base<T>>{
    using refined_type = std::pair<typename Base::InternalType, typename Base::InternalType>;
    Base<refined_type> refined_storage;
};
```

You'll have to use a template specialization to get a concrete type from a template template.

This is used like so:

```
using injector_int = Injector<Base<int>>;

int main(){
    injector_int i;
}
```

[here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac34fe8e46543dd2)

Comment: *that just adds to compile time* => does it? I mean is there any measurable effect on performance? This seems to be an unsubstantiated claim, which distracts from the main point: your solution is *simpler* than a rebind, and simple is better (in general).

Comment: @MatthieuM. compile time does not affect performance, so I'm not really sure what you mean. But yes, adding in another class for rebinding should theoretically cause the compiler to do more work; even if only in parsing the extra source.

Comment: I was talking about compilation performance :) It's just that as far as I am concerned this comment is quite unnecessary and may detract from the main point (the answer itself).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, you're right; I'll take that out haha.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide an external rebinder:

```
template <class Bound, class U>
struct rebinder;

template <template <class> class Binder, class B, class U>
struct rebinder<Binder<B>, U>
{
  typedef Binder<U> type;
};

// Usage:

template <typename Base>
class Injector
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<typename Base::InternalType, typename Base::InternalType> RefinedType;
    typename rebinder<Base, RefinedType>::type refinedStorage;
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5608975b52330bd3)

Comment: Ha, I just noticed that we have the same answer. Er. +1 I guess :)